# WiFi is not supported by emulator

Tags: android

Can anyone let me know how can I test android WiFi programs on emulator?
I searched and found WiFi is not supported by emulator.

Comment: I know I can test it on real device.I want to know some other option.

Comment: You could try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) if the licensing is appropriate for you.

Comment: Better you can download GenyMotion from https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc and use it

Answer (score -2):

No, Android Emulator don't support WiFi, so don't waste your time. However you can try other alternatives, I suggest you to use [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)